# SQL SELECT multiple count in one query

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count

I have these two tables:

[image: two tables]

and I want get this result:

[image: result]

How can I achieve this by using only one query?

I tried with join and count and group by but I cannot get it right.

I tried this already, but I cannot get it to work properly.

```
SELECT
    coupon.*,
    couponUsers.returned AS COUPON_TOTAL_USERS,
    couponUses.returned AS COUPON_TOTAL_USES
FROM
    coupon,
    (SELECT
         coupon.COUPON_CODE,
         COUNT(redeemed.REDEEMED_USER) AS returned
     FROM
         coupon
     JOIN 
         redeemed ON coupon.COUPON_CODE = redeemed.REDEEMED_CODE
     GROUP BY
         redeemed.REDEEMED_USER) couponUsers,
    (SELECT
         coupon.COUPON_CODE,
         COUNT(redeemed.REDEEMED_CODE) AS returned
     FROM
         coupon
     JOIN 
         redeemed ON coupon.COUPON_CODE = redeemed.REDEEMED_CODE
     GROUP BY
         redeemed.REDEEMED_CODE) couponUses
WHERE 
    coupon.COUPON_CODE = couponUsers.COUPON_CODE 
    AND coupon.COUPON_CODE = couponUses.COUPON_CODE
GROUP BY
    coupon.COUPON_CODE
ORDER BY
    coupon.COUPON_ID ASC
```

This is the build schema if you want to try it yourself in SQL fiddle or something like that..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coupon` 
(
    `COUPON_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `COUPON_CODE` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `coupon` (`COUPON_ID`, `COUPON_CODE`) VALUES 
(1, "AAAAA"),
(2, "BBBBB"),
(3, "CCCCC"),
(4, "DDDDD"),
(5, "EEEEE");

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `redeemed` (
  `REDEEMED_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `REDEEMED_USER` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `REDEEMED_CODE` varchar(32) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `redeemed` (`REDEEMED_ID`, `REDEEMED_USER`, `REDEEMED_CODE`) VALUES 
(1, "TOM", "AAAAA"),
(2, "PAULA", "BBBBB"),
(3, "TOBI", "CCCCC"),
(4, "JANA", "DDDDD"),
(5, "INGO", "EEEEE"),
(6, "TOM", "AAAAA"),
(7, "PETER", "EEEEE"),
(8, "JIM", "DDDDD"),
(9, "SARA", "AAAAA"),
(10, "TOBI", "CCCCC"),
(11, "PAULA", "AAAAA"),
(12, "TOM", "AAAAA"),
(13, "PAULA", "BBBBB"),
(14, "JIM", "DDDDD"),
(15, "JANA", "DDDDD");
```

i am trying this already a couple hours..
its time for some help ^^

Comment: Hey there, try posting some programming code, it'll boost your chances on receiving answers.

Comment: You can use a join query to join `COUPON_CODE` and `REDEEMED_CODE` and do the count on the other columns. Please add tables in text format if you want more helpful answers please also code you're tried as well

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne i added tables (build schema) and my wasted code ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to generate the wanted counts in a single table query:

```
select 
       redeemed_code
     , count(*) as tot_uses
     , count(distinct redeemed_user) as tot_users
from redeemed
group by redeemed_code
```

You can join this to the coupon table for final output, for example with a left join you would get all coupons listed in `coupon` even if none have been redeemed yet.

```
 select
      c.coupon_id
    , c.coupon_code
    , coalesce(d.tot_uses,0) as tot_uses
    , coalesce(d.tot_users,0) as tot_users
from coupon as c
left join (
         select 
                 redeemed_code
              ,  count(*) as tot_uses
              , count(distinct redeemed_user) as tot_users
         from redeemed
         group by redeemed_code
         ) as d on c.coupon_code = d.redeemed_code
```

| coupon_id | coupon_code | tot_uses | tot_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAAA | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | BBBBB | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | CCCCC | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | DDDDD | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | EEEEE | 2 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78c43f805017cd69522949fada2af1b5)*

Comment: i tryed your code but this is not working.

Comment: wrong column referenced, sorry was trying to answer using a phone

Comment: thanks alot, thats so helpful and working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is for PostgreSQL, but this query should work for you. You can do the `GROUP BY` on the `redeemed` table and join that with `coupon` to get the `COUPON_ID`. \

```
psql=# WITH redeemed_query AS (
        SELECT 
                "REDEEMED_CODE", 
                COUNT(*) AS "TOTAL_USES", 
                COUNT(DISTINCT("REDEEMED_USER")) AS "TOTAL_USERS" 
        from redeemed GROUP BY "REDEEMED_CODE"
) 
SELECT * FROM redeemed_query 
INNER JOIN 
coupon ON redeemed_query."REDEEMED_CODE" = coupon."COUPON_CODE";


 REDEEMED_CODE | TOTAL_USES | TOTAL_USERS | COUPON_ID | COUPON_CODE 
---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------
 AAAAA         |          5 |           3 |         1 | AAAAA
 BBBBB         |          2 |           1 |         2 | BBBBB
 CCCCC         |          2 |           1 |         3 | CCCCC
 DDDDD         |          4 |           2 |         4 | DDDDD
 EEEEE         |          2 |           2 |         5 | EEEEE
(5 rows)
```

Comment: thank you, i dont use postgreSQL but maybe this is also helpful for someone else in future :)

Comment: The query should still work for you, the quotation marks should just be replace by tick marks ` .